# Vertical scrolling on SlickGrid doesn't have any effects when hovering over frozen columns

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

It works properly when hovering over non-frozen columns:
![screen with the example][1]

Why does it happen?
What information could help to debug the problem?

The same question on the 6pac/SlickGrid fork:
https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/issues/528

UPD. Example: https://angular-empty-project-zoc3ab.stackblitz.io/
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLZSP.png

Comment: We would need to see your SlickGrid JS code. It seems that issue was fixed according to your Git issue. Therefore, the issue must be on your end.

Comment: http://slickgrid.net/SubmitAnIssue.html

Comment: Thank you, guys.
I'll try to prepare an example.

Comment: Please, check the update with the example https://angular-empty-project-zoc3ab.stackblitz.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont forget to include script "SlickGrid-2.4.29/lib/jquery.mousewheel.js" on your page.

Answer (score 0):

SlickGrid uses 2 `<div>` containers and because of that only the last one will have the scroll working, you need to do some jQuery tricks to have mouse scrolling work

```js
// with frozen (pinned) grid, in order to see the entire row being highlighted when hovering
// we need to do some extra tricks (that is because frozen grids use 2 separate div containers)
// the trick is to use row selection to highlight when hovering current row and remove selection once we're not
grid.onMouseEnter.subscribe(event => {
      const cell = this.gridObj.getCellFromEvent(event);
      grid.setSelectedRows([cell.row]); // highlight current row
      event.preventDefault();
});
grid.onMouseLeave.subscribe(event => {
      grid.setSelectedRows([]); // remove highlight
      event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the suggestion.

I solved it thanks to @Sadri Lassoued and his answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64258426/14163843
it helps.